# How to force Flash player to play audio stream of a video file?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, audio-streaming

I'm quite new to Flash and coming across a question.

I'm trying to force the Flash player to play video files without showing screens. I did try to set `vidDisplay.visible` to `false`. But it seemed not working at all.

Any ideas?

Edit: Thanks for the replays. Sorry, I should have made my question clearer. Actually, what I was doing was try to build a generic media player. Whatever the source is(audio or video), the control panel always the same, namely, a mp3 player panel is always displayed:

However, when I stream in a video file, it would end up overriding mp3 panel with a partial video screen. I don't have enough reputation to upload images...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's enough if you put a non-transparent big rectangle on the top of the video. That would hide the video content but not the sound.

Comment: Yes, hiding the video player using some method, such as this one, is the way to go.  The audio and video data are usually interleaved.  Unless you have something server-side splitting them apart, you won't save any bandwidth anyway.